stm32h723+w25q64 linker script
I am trying to link w25q64 flsh memory to stm32h723 microcontroller. ewerything seems good untill im trying to debug mcu.
[build] Memory region         Used Size  Region Size  %age Used
[build]          DTCMRAM:          0 GB       128 KB      0.00%
[build]              RAM:       29184 B       128 KB     22.27%
[build]           RAM_D2:          0 GB        32 KB      0.00%
[build]           RAM_D3:          0 GB        16 KB      0.00%
[build]          ITCMRAM:          0 GB        64 KB      0.00%
[build]            FLASH:      109824 B         1 MB     10.47%
[build]           W25Q64:          2 KB         8 MB      0.02%
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:04.211
[build] Build finished with exit code 0

But when im select upload code there anways an error.
Reading symbols from c:/ST/STM32CubeCLT_1.16.0/GNU-tools-for-STM32/bin/arm-none-eabi-objdump.exe --syms -C -h -w C:/Users/USER/Documents/FIRMWARE/Vs code/CubeMX/build/Debug/CubeMX.elf
Reading symbols from c:/st/stm32cubeclt_1.16.0/gnu-tools-for-stm32/bin/arm-none-eabi-nm.exe --defined-only -S -l -C -p C:/Users/USER/Documents/FIRMWARE/Vs code/CubeMX/build/Debug/CubeMX.elf
Launching GDB: "c:\\ST\\STM32CubeCLT_1.16.0/GNU-tools-for-STM32/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb" -q --interpreter=mi2
    IMPORTANT: Set "showDevDebugOutput": "raw" in "launch.json" to see verbose GDB transactions here. Very helpful to debug issues or report problems
Setting GDB-Server CWD: c:\ST\STM32CubeCLT_1.16.0/STLink-gdb-server/bin
Launching gdb-server: "c:\\ST\\STM32CubeCLT_1.16.0/STLink-gdb-server/bin/ST-LINK_gdbserver" -p 50000 -cp "c:\\ST\\STM32CubeCLT_1.16.0/STM32CubeProgrammer/bin" --swd --halt -m 0
    Please check TERMINAL tab (gdb-server) for output from c:\ST\STM32CubeCLT_1.16.0/STLink-gdb-server/bin/ST-LINK_gdbserver
Finished reading symbols from objdump: Time: 172 ms
Finished reading symbols from nm: Time: 230 ms
Output radix now set to decimal 10, hex a, octal 12.
Input radix now set to decimal 10, hex a, octal 12.
ST-LINK: GDB Server Quit Unexpectedly. See gdb-server output in TERMINAL tab for more details.`

How to fix it ? I want to store data in it without usind spi read and write functions.
I have checked connections, stlink is fine. I have added
    /* Arrays to be placed in W25Q64 external memory */
    .w25q64_data :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.w25q64_data)
        *(.w25q64_data*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } >W25Q64

to a link sript and i added
uint8_t large_array[2048] __attribute__((section(".w25q64_data"))) = {0};

to main c.
it works until im tryig to  make something like
    for (int i = 0; i < 2048; i++) {
        large_array[i] = i % 256;
    }


External flash is ROM. You can't just treat it like RAM and write to it like large_array[i] = i % 256;. Flash memory simply doesn't work like this. So if this is the only problem, then there is no problem and it is simply expected behavior. You can read like you would from RAM, but you can't erase/write like that.
